# Xcode C++ code in cocoa app about serial port get operation not permitted

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, c++11, serial-port

I build a code in `Xcode` console with `C++` project works perfectly before:

[image: Photo]

```cpp
#include "SerialPort.hpp"
#include "TypeAbbreviations.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    //* Open port, and connect to a device
    const char devicePathStr[] = "/dev/tty.usbserial-A104RXG4";
    const int baudRate = 9600;
    int sfd = openAndConfigureSerialPort(devicePathStr, baudRate);
    if (sfd < 0) {
        if (sfd == -1) {
            printf("Unable to connect to serial port.\n");
        }
        else { //sfd == -2
            printf("Error setting serial port attributes.\n");
        }
        return 0;
    }

    // * Read using readSerialData(char* bytes, size_t length)

    // * Write using writeSerialData(const char* bytes, size_t length)

    // * Remember to flush potentially buffered data when necessary

    // * Close serial port when done
    const char dataToWrite[]="abcd";
    char databuffer[1024];

    while(1){
        readSerialData(databuffer, 4);
        sleep(2);
        writeSerialData(databuffer, 4);
        sleep(2);

    }

    printf("end.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

After this build, I tried to migrate it to my `Xcode` cocoa application with `C++` wrappers below.

[image: Photo]

I am pretty sure my `Wrapper` works fine with test `C++` code. That means, I can call `C++` function from my `ViewController.swift`.

But there's one strange thing happened. I am not able to open connection with the following code:

```
    sfd = open(portPath, (O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY));
    if (sfd == -1) {
        printf("Unable to open serial port: %s at baud rate: %d\n", portPath, baudRate);
        printf("%s", std::strerror(errno));
        return sfd;
    }
```

There error message returns :

```
Unable to open serial port: /dev/tty.usbserial-A104RXG4 at baud rate: 9600
Operation not permitted
```

I've tried to change `app sandbox configuration`, set up my `system preference` to grant access to my `app`, also I disabled my `rootless`. (`csrutil` disable with `command + R`)
But the problem still persists:

[image: Problem] &
[image: Problem]

I want to ask that:
1. Why my code on `Xcode C++` project works fine but fail on `swift's cocoa` app on `Xcode`?
2. How to solve the `"Operation not permitted"` Issue.

My `Xcode` version is `11.3.1` and `Mac OS` is `10.14.6 Mojave`.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out myself.

It's APP sandbox is bothering me.
All you need to do is turn off sandbox
Turn off it by click X on the mouse point.
If you want to add it back, just click +Capability and put it back on.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOc18.jpg

reference : https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/94177#285075

Comment: Don’t turn off Sandbox instead add exceptions refer - https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AppSandboxTemporaryExceptionEntitlements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH5-SW3